# Sendmail not working as desired in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, sendmail

This is the code I have in a bash script that runs as a cronjob. The cronjob run as root.

```
   /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@email.com<<EOF
   subject:Backup Error!
   from:backup@server01
   $error
        EOF
```

There is code after this and the email I get is as follows:

From the root user on the machine.

and the message includes:

```
   subject:Backup Error!
   from:backup@server01
   $error
        EOF
   More code...
   that is in the script
   all the way to the end...
```

I have tried other variations, this is the closest I've got. I tried this in a regular script and it worked properly. Whats going on, and how can I send this email, specifying the subject and form sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers have already mentioned:

- bad end of "here document" (END)
- missing empty line between headers and body

Additional fixes:

- `-i` command line option to stop special treatment for lines starting with dot
- `--` to separate command line options from addresses of recipients 
      (good style recomendation)

Corrected script:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- myemail@email.com <<EOF
subject: Backup Error!
from:backup@server01

$error
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not use any whitespace character in front or after the second limit string `EOF`. If you use just only one space in front or after the limit string, that special-purpose code block will never work. So, use only:

```
EOF
```

And you should read some bash scripting guides in this sense like [Chapter 19. Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail (and email in general, it seems) requires a blank line between headers and body. The following example worked.

```
$ sendmail oli@mydomain.com <<EOF
> subject: testing
> from: oli2@mydomain.com
> 
> This is my body!
> EOF
```

(Obviously pasting that in with the `>`s in there won't work, just alter what you're doing so that there's a blank line between your headers and error message).